# Is there a special case in which wave atoms convert to curvelets?

Tags: transform, wave

I'm new to multi scale transformations. I was wondering if there is a special case where wave atom converts to curvelet transform? Can I use wave atom parameters to have curvelet properties?

Comment: Thank you for this question. A natural interrogation would be: why would you want to use wave atoms instead of curvelets, and what curvelet properties are you interested in?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Because I could not handle 3D curvelet code to use under windows 64-bit and MATLAB environment.

Comment: Understood. Being closer to packets, and less elongated, they may behave a little differently. However, the reduced sparsity of wave atoms can be useful to tune in practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their 2007 paper, [Wave atoms and sparsity of oscillatory patterns](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.acha.2007.03.003), Demanet and Ying  draw connections between wave atoms and other types of wavelets:

[image: Wave atoms,]

In plain words:

> We introduce “wave atoms” as a variant of 2D wavelet packets obeying
>   the parabolic scaling wavelength

with a better spatial localization, meant for texture analysis. Their choice ($\alpha=\beta=1/2$) was a compromise between two types of sparsification (preservation under warping, sparsity of oscillations). Yet, one could built different  collections of such wave packets, with alternative  choices of  $\alpha$ and $\beta$, bridging the gap between the different transform choices.

Yet, their natural redundancy is 2,  with an orthonormal variant, and a complex one with redundancy 4, different from that of the curvelets. So I do no think they can be used as a special case of curvelets.

A tutorial on 2D geometric transformation can be obtain in A [Panorama on Multiscale Geometric Representations, Intertwining Spatial, Directional and Frequency Selectivity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.sigpro.2011.04.025), 2011.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I meant "is there a parameter in wave atom formulation to convert it to curvelet transform?"

Comment: So the global answer is no. From the paper, this is a fixed transformation (ie non-parametric)